# Android Presentation API - Interactive Secondary Display?

Tags: android

I'm building an Android Application on a SoC Board that runs Android Nougat. I have a primary HDMI Display that I connect to via the HDMI Port, and a secondary HDMI Display that I connect to via a USB-C to HDMI Converter. By default, the secondary display mirrors the primary one.

I've loaded in the Android Presentation API's Display Manager example, and I'm able to select my secondary HDMI Display, and a photo opens on it.

However, what I noticed is that my mouse is bound inside my primary display, and it can't travel to the secondary display. This isn't ideal because I want my secondary display to be interactive as well, through a touch screen display. Now, I don't want to invest in it yet as it can cost quite a lot.

My question is: Can the secondary display in the Presentation API be interacted with as well and act as if it's an "entirely separate app" from the one displayed in the primary display?

Comment: That is likely to depend a lot on your hardware and your Android build. I suspect that you will have better luck on Android 8.0+ using its [multi-display support](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0#mds) rather than `Presentation`.

Comment: @CommonsWare sadly, Android 8.0+ isn't available for the SoC I'm using (Rock960) as of now.

Comment: Considering that Android 8.0 is two years old, perhaps you should be reconsidering your choice of SoC.